# ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am getting the below error while trying to run HBASE with HADOOP
HBASE 0.98.x
HADOOP 2.4.0

```
    ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.had$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMCl$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluste$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.j$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMaste$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommand$
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandL$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2793)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot c$
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedF$
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:144$
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:895)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init$
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruc$
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Delegating$
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMCl$
    ... 7 more
```

Do i have to set configuration property at hbase-site.xml. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which version of HBase did you downloaded? Be sure you get the corresponding version with the same hadoop version you have (version 2). On your case you should download 
$ wget http://apache.rediris.es/hbase/stable/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz
instead of
$ wget http://apache.rediris.es/hbase/stable/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop1-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are editing the correct files under hbase/conf.